# Getting Odd Warning In Console React Router

Tags: reactjs

Warning: You should not use `<Route render>` and `<Route children>` in the same route; `<Route children>` will be ignored

I am getting this message, but I do not see anywhere where I am calling Route Children and Render in the same route besides the main index.js where I am wrapping

```
<BrowserRouter><App/></BrowserRouter>
```

Here is my REPO https://github.com/mtrew2015/front-end-project-week

If you can figure this out, I will greatly appreciate it!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the following Route

```
<Route path="/view/:id" render={(props) => (<ViewNote {...props} deleteNote={this.deleteNote} updateNote={this.updateNote} notes={this.state.notes} loggedIn={this.state.isLoggedIn} />)}> </Route>
```

You have a `space` in between the opening and closing JSX tags which acts as `children` and hence you get the warning. Remove that space and it would work.

However to avoid such errors, you could simply use self closing tags with JSX components that don't need to have children

```
<Route path="/view/:id" render={(props) => (
        <ViewNote
             {...props} 
             deleteNote={this.deleteNote}
             updateNote={this.updateNote}
             notes={this.state.notes}
             loggedIn={this.state.isLoggedIn}  
        />
)} />
```

[Working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/yq10l0ywwz)

Comment: Oh wow, perfect. I didn't realize that a space would be treated as a child. Yes, I will use self-closing tags in the future. Thanks so much!

Comment: Glad to have helped :-)

Comment: will award correct answer as soon as it permits me, thanks for the fast response!